# CSV file to Key Value pairs Python 3

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

```
import csv

def csv_to_kvs(fileName):
  stringFloats = []
  with open(fileName,'r') as csvFile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    for row in csvreader:
      stringFloats.append(row)
    print(stringFloats)
```

I am trying to take a CSV file that is in string,float,float,float format of 10 rows and I have to make the string become a key-value pair with all the floats on the corresponding row.

So if the CSV file is:
age,16,17,18
area,1,7,4
call,2,3,6

The code needs to return {age:[16,17,18],etc...}. Any steps in the right direction are appreciated. I am learning CSV file reading and don't understand it too well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read the row, you have the dictionary key in column 0 and the values in the remaining columns. You can slice the row, optionally converting to float on the way, and assign to the needed dict.

import csv

```
def csv_to_kvs(fileName):
    stringFloats = {}
    with open(fileName,'r') as csvFile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvFile)
        for row in csvreader:
            # assuming 1 and following should be floats 
            stringFloats[row[0]] = [float(val) for val in row[1:]]
        print(stringFloats)
    return stringFloats
```

(...and come to terms with 4 space indentation!)